# Need a Software to compress videos

Tags: windows, archiving, file-compression

I have many videos that I want to compress. I've tried 7z. But it could only marginally compress a 188 MB video to a 184 MB archive.

Are there any better available alternatives??

I'm willing to start with lossy compression, because I am not particularly uncomfortable with a wee-bit quality quality loss. If the quality loss is too much, then I would try the lossless compression.

I am running Windows-7 32-bit.

---

EDIT:
The following information bytes may help you guide me to a good answer:

1. I checked out the codec details using MediaInfo. In short, it's using the AVC codec. In full, it's like this: 372 Kbps (350 Kbps), 550*412 (4:3), at 25.00 fps, AVC (NTSC) (Main@L3.1) (CABAC/3 Ref Frames). But I must confess...I can't seem to make much sense of this full detail.. :)
2. I tried Handbrake. But it ended up increasing the video file's size by 3x instead of compressing it! But I must also add that with Handbrake, I only tries using it to transcode to MKV & MP4. No other setting (like frame size) was changed  in this transcode exercise through Handbrake.

Comment: Depends on the codec of the video. If the video already has a good compression, then I'm afraid you won't be squeezing more out of it.

Comment: Another consideration is quality. Are we talking about lossless compression here – or would it be OK if "smaller file size" comes at the cost of some quality loss (e.g. less resolution, or "JPEG-like compression")?

Comment: @MarioWerner I checked out the codec details using MediaInfo. In short, it's using the AVC codec. In full, it's like this: 372 Kbps (350 Kbps), 550*412 (4:3), at 25.00 fps, AVC (NTSC) (Main@L3.1) (CABAC/3 Ref Frames).

But I must confess...I can't seem to make much sense of this full detail.. :)

Comment: @Izzy Could you please elaborate or guide me to a link which could make me understand the difference between the compression techniques?

Comment: Please see [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Video) of Wikipedia's data compression page.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the wiki section link! I think I should try both...because I am not particularly uncomfortable with a wee-bit quality quality loss. Let me try both. If the quality loss is too much, then I would try the lossless compression.

Comment: 372Kbps is already on the low side for the size and bitrate of video you have. I think your only option is to accept reduced size and/or quality so that in turn you can reduce that bitrate. If you make the frames 400*300 for example, you should be able to reduce the bit-rate. You can also reduce frame rate to 12.5 fps - it will be bad if there's lots of motion, but otherwise not too noticeable (older mobile .mp4 and .3gp files often used this trick).

Comment: @NeilSlater Oh..Okay! Thanks. Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I may accept it as an answer.

Comment: I think the recommendation of Handbrake (or ffmpeg) is probably a good one, but you will need to experiment with params before getting reasonable result. Do you have a small, short video in same format that you are storing, that you are able to share? (It's been my day job before to work with video transcoding, so I should be able to figure out a reasonable start for you pretty quickly, but I'd need a sample)

Comment: @NeilSlater That would be a great jumpstarter!! Please see this video: http://jmp.sh/ary1iSm Please ignore the audio being out-of sync in this one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well If you want to resize or use lossy compression there is [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), You might like it If you want to compress raw videos, like screen capture. Otherwise modern video codecs are already capable and there is high chance your video is as compressed as it could be, without loss of quality.

Hand brake can compress, i.e. either resize or use better codecs, `.mp4` for high compression.

Note that resizing video will have a significant decrease in size but also a decrease in quality. thus you might want to experiment the correct ratio till when the quality is *acceptable* for **you**.

Comment: Hi! I tried Handbrake. But it ended up increasing the video file's size by 3x instead of compressing it!

Comment: @beck2ham: You need to specify target bitrate using `-b` option. The video is variable-rate, so it is safer for quality reasons to leave framerate unchanged. Here's command line options that reduce size by 30% or so: `HandBrakeCLI -i example.mp4 -b 200 -2 -w 400 -l 300 -o smaller_example.mp4` If you are not using command-line version, then that's video bit-rate 200Kbps, 2-pass encoding, width 400 height 200. This leaves audio as-is (you could also reduce audio bitrate, but give nature of the content, reducing video size/quality has less noticeable effect than reducing audio)

Comment: @Aditya: I suggest adding the command line example (or other notes from the comment) as an example to show how Handbrake can help solve OPs problem in more detail.

Comment: @beck2ham: Slightly more aggressive settings can get around 50% smaller files, and the quality seems OK to me: `HandBrakeCLI -i example.mp4 -b 140 --ab 48 -2 -w 400 -l 300 -r 12 --pfr --mixdown mono -o smaller_example.mp4` - that's 140Kbps video, 48Kbps audio, 2-pass encoding, 400 x 300, target framerate 12fps (setting that as max rate), and setting audio channels to mono (getting relatively better quality for lower bitrate at expense of no more stereo)